# ros rviz pointcloud point selection

Tags: rviz, pcl, ros-kinetic, pcl-ros, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

This page on rviz display types http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/PointCloud on the ros website mentions a attribute that the pointcloud type is "selectable". I'm not sure what that means exactly but it sounds like something I want.

I would like to display a pointcloud, and qualitatively analyse it. During this, I would like to select a point or a group of points through mouseclicks and do simple analysis like get the point coordinates or compute the group centroid etc.

Does rviz allow you to do that?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284833/ros-rviz-pointcloud-point-selection/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, Rviz is mainly for visualization. What you want to do (select a point/group of points through mouseclicks, etc) should be done using PCL library or your private methods. Then you publish your results in Rviz for display.

---

Originally posted by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) with karma: 358 on 2018-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-03-08**:
Hmm. Do you know if I could get back stuff like the mouseclick locations, viewpoints, projections from rviz? Then I could go ahead and use that for my methods.

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-03-08**:
I did a quick search and this [#q69019](https://answers.ros.org/question/69019/how-to-point-and-click-on-rviz-map-and-output-the-position/) turned up :) It seems like you can select a point and its position will be printed out.